# How should I save my graphics with only 2 colors?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I had this problem for quite long. Some websites allow us to upload only JPG, PNG and GIF files. When I upload something with only 2-3 colors in these formats the edges got very ugly and it's quite visible. It does not happen on my own website though, only on those that may re-format/resize my pictures. The same happens on Instagram, both on feed and profile picture.

Bad result here:

[image]

Comment: Uploaded, it's pretty visible what's wrong around the edges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are jpeg artefacts caused by too much lossy compression. If you uploaded the images to facebook/instagram for example, these convert all images to jpeg, resize them, and add more compression.  There's little you can do except perhaps reduce the image size, and convert the images to jpeg yourself, in order to keep the file size as low as you can so that the website adds less compression.

There's a help page on facebook that gives advice on how to avoid such problems [here](https://www.facebook.com/help/1703757313215897/?helpref=hc_fnav) - click on the section that says "How can I make sure that my photos display in the highest possible quality?"

Comment: Why is jpeg artification (I invented that word) so much more pronounced with red?

Comment: @mayersdesign I don't know for sure, but it seems to have something to do with the high level of contrast between large solid areas of red and white. I've experienced the problem myself.  Social networking sites serve so many images to users that they have little choice but to add more compression to try to keep file sizes down, and also to help users to view images on mobile devices with slow internet connection speeds.

Comment: Your suggestion gave me better results, but it's still bad. Thank you anyways :)

Comment: I've never seen a properly formatted vector or profile pic look bad on social sites. They compress them enough to display correctly at the profile or thumbnail size. Only when you zoom all the way in or open it in an art program do you see the problem.

Comment: I agree with Webster.  @Stefan, what export settings are you using?  Have you checked that the JPG *you've* created is high quality in the first place?